# OpenSSL Verification certificate callback - Is it possible to use a lambda or a class function for callback?

Tags: c++, openssl, c++17

Is it possible to pass to this function:

```
 void SSL_CTX_set_verify(SSL_CTX *ctx, int mode, int (*verify_callback)(int, X509_STORE_CTX *));
```

a lambda function with & or this parameter? Or do I have to use a global variable?

I've tried

```
auto lambda = [this](int preverify_ok, X509_STORE_CTX* x509_ctx) {
    return 0;
};
```

but as you know probably it doesn't work because **No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called**. It works well without this parameter.

I would like to avoid use a global variable. I'm using now C++17.
I know that there wasn't possible to pass class function in older C++ but maybe times have already changed?

Comment: Nothing changed. You can't cast a stateful lambda (with filled capture list) into a function pointer. A function pointer can't hold data. OpenSSL is written in C, then the usage expects C techniques. Maybe you could be making a wrapper for it in C++.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it isn't possible. :)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only convert a lambda function *without* captures into a function pointer.

Instead, use [`SSL_CTX_set_ex_data` and `SSL_CTX_get_ex_data`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_get_ex_data.html) to stash your `this` pointer in the `SSL_CTX` object.
You can obtain the `idx` argument by calling [`SSL_CTX_get_ex_new_index`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_get_ex_new_index.html) once at the start of your program.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't know about this option. :)